# Complete something not according to the context in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I use zsh with the “new” completion system (`compinit`). Sometimes I want to restrict completion to a subset of what is possible, to cut down on ambiguity. This is a user choice, not a configuration setting: I want to hit a different key instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get a different set of completions. **I don't want to configure completions differently for that command**. <kbd>Tab</kbd> should still do its normal thing.

In some cases, there are workarounds. For example, I have a key bound to `_bash_complete-word`, which in most cases completes files. But sometimes I want a less common focus. For example:

- Complete only host names after `scp`, not local file names.
- Complete only remote names after `git checkout`, not branch names.

How can I bind a key that will complete remote names after `git checkout`, but not branch names? More generally, how can I bind a key to complete something different from what would normally be completed in the current context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet below causes <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to complete git remote names when on a git command line, and host names elsewhere.

```
_complete-remotes () {
  case $words[1] in
    git) load_helper_functions _git; __git_remotes;;
    *) _hosts;;
  esac
}
compdef -k _complete-remotes complete-word '^[r'
```

- See [Can I use a helper function from a ZSH completion file in another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403820/can-i-use-a-helper-function-from-a-zsh-completion-file-in-another) for `load_helper_functions`. If you remove it from the code above, it will only work if completion for `git` has been performed at least once before in the current zsh session.
- [`$words[1]`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words) is the first word of the command-with-arguments that is to be completed.
- [`complete -k …`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef) registers the function `_complete-remotes` as a completion widget (which allows it to run completion builtins) and binds it to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.